# SSRS Subreports Duplicating

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

All of a sudden my subreports are being duplicated in a tablix.  I have it broke down to a tablix with one row and one sub report in a data cell.  I pass one parameter from the main reports parameter collection.  And another sub report parameter is hard coded. Here is the design view.

[image: Design View]

Here is the preview for the report.
[image: Preview Mode]

What is really strange is the original report has worked for years, and just today it started to duplicate the sub reports.  So I made this spike to see if it was the report or something I am doing wrong.  I have tried to google this issue but either there was nothing I could find, or I could not figure out the search question adequately.

Comment: check your dataset.. could it be that there is more than one row returned in your parent report? Looks like your subreport is in the detail group.. so one for every row returned..

Comment: There was not a data set being returned.  It is just a bunch of sub reports with a different hard coded parameter.  It makes a nicer print out on paper.  But you were correct see my own answer I just figured out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the sub report was included in the default details group.  The main report does not have a dataset returned.  It is just used for layout and to collect a parameter to pass to the sub reports.  I deleted the details group, but left the rows and data, and everything works.  I still do not understand why the report thought there were 2 rows, the tablix datasource was null?  Or why it changed since last year.  But it is working now.